# Getting specific properties with for-in loop

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

Is the 'for in' loop limited to showing only property names, and their first values, or is there a way for you see inside their values values? For example,

if i want to check the 'titles' property values inside of 'no1' object, that is located in 'favBooks' object, can i do it with for in loop?

I was trying something like this:

```
var favBooks = {
  no1:{Title:'Sidhartha',Author:'Hesse'},
  no2:{Title:'Cosmos',Author:'Sagan'},
  no3:{Title:'Idiot',Author:'Dostojevski'}
}
```

and then calling only the titles with for in:

```
for(t in favBooks) console.log(favBooks[t.title]);
```

..but it returns undefined.

I know there are other ways to do this, but my question is: Is this the limitation of 'for in' - to only return property names and their first values, or can you go deeper into properties,and if yes - how?

Thanks

Comment: `Title is not title` ( capital). `favBooks[t.Title]` will work fine

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is, basically, a typo.

Comment: It's not only a typo, problem is the way accessing the data from the object. Try changing `favBooks[t.title]` to `favBooks[t].Title`

Comment: @AshishKumar, yes that was the problem, i made the typo only when asking question on stack. But it was the way of accessing data that i didn't know how to write. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(t in favBooks) console.log(favBooks[t].Title);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line 
    console.log(favBooks[t.title]);`

Aside from having "title" instead of "Title" (javascript is case-sensitive), the property "Title" isn't an index of the object favBooks. You might be able to index it with favBooks["no1"] (I haveb't tried that) but you definitely could with favBooks.no1

eg

```
favBooks.no1.Title would be "Sidhartha".
```

so I think that last line should be:

```
for(t in favBooks) console.log(favBooks[t].Title); // logs the Title property
```

The function below runs through a javascript object and makes a string representation of it. If you alert the result, it'll reveal the structure of the object.
Also it traverses the object with

```
for (X in el)
```

where el is any object- be it a DIV element in the html doc or a {a:b,c:d} type object.

perhaps that will help ?

```
function dump(el) {
var s=""; //    
for (X in el) { 
      if (el[X]) {var sX=el[X].toString(); s+=X+": "+el[X] + "<br>\n"} 
    }
return s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something closer to PHP `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` :

```
var favBooks = [                      // <-- note this is now an array
  {Title:'Sidhartha',Author:'Hesse'},
  {Title:'Cosmos',Author:'Sagan'},
  {Title:'Idiot',Author:'Dostojevski'}
]

favBooks.forEach (function(elt){ console.log (elt.Title); })
```

Note that **this will not work on IE8-**